# Operation not allowed for a result set of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Tags: java, mysql

I have this code:

```
    public static ArrayList<TicketData> readDB(Connection pConnection) 
{
    TicketData lSingleTicketData;
    ArrayList<TicketData> lTicketData = new ArrayList<TicketData>();
    Statement lStatement;
    ResultSet lResultSet;

    try 
    {
        lStatement = pConnection.createStatement();
        lResultSet = lStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.ticket");
        lResultSet.first();

        while(!lResultSet.isAfterLast())
        {
            lSingleTicketData = new TicketData(lResultSet.getString(1) ,lResultSet.getDate(2).toLocalDate(),lResultSet.getInt(3));
            lTicketData.add(lSingleTicketData);
            lResultSet.next();
        }
     } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error at the execution + " + ex.getMessage());
    } 
  return lTicketData; 
}
```

But when execute this code I am getting this :

```
Operation not allowed for a result set of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Javadoc for `ResultSet.first()`:

```
    /**
     * Moves the cursor to the first row in
     * this <code>ResultSet</code> object.
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if the cursor is on a valid row;
     * <code>false</code> if there are no rows in the result set
     * @exception SQLException if a database access error
     * occurs; this method is called on a closed result set
     * or the result set type is <code>TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY</code>
     * @exception SQLFeatureNotSupportedException if the JDBC driver does not support
     * this method
     * @since 1.2
     */
    boolean first() throws SQLException;
```

The usual way to iterate over a result set is:

```
while (rs.next()) {
...
}
```

You are making it much more complicated than you need to.